# Save php variables safely

Tags: php, forms, variables

Hi i need to safe php value to some file no to database. I have this simple form:

index.php

```
<form action="settings.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="width" value="">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and

settings.php

```
<?php 

$width = $_POST["width"];

$fp = FOpen("file.txt", "w+");
$fp3 = "$width"; 

FPutS($fp, $fp3); 
FClose($fp); 

header("location: index.php"); 
?>
```

I need to protect my file.txt because if someone know about this, than he can modify my file.txt from another server.

Thanks for help

Comment: If you can, place the file outside the web root. That's the safest thing you can do

Comment: Just how do you think that someone can "can modify my file.txt from another server"?

Comment: If someone can modify it 'from another server', they can open your PHP files and break anything anyway.

Comment: @CaptainPayalytic, it's a web form, anyone posting to it will automatically write to the file assuming the form's not secured by means of authentication.

Comment: @Alfo This is true, but it does not require another server and also this would be true for adding things to a database. The OP was suggesting that something particular in his code made it vulnerable to being modified from another server. If we are to tell him how to stop this particular thing, we need to know what it is he expects to be happening. I agree that his code is so un-secure  this is the least of his problems, but that is what he has asked!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, nobody can modify your text file...what you want to do is create a .htaccess file and put it in the directory of file.txt.

goto notepad and type this

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^google.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

goto save and type no name but just .htaccess and put it in the directory of the text file.

Comment: It's true that no one can *directly* modify the text file from another server, but anyone with access to the form could, simply by way of submitting the form (invoking the PHP script to write the form input. You can "hide" it from search engines with the proper meta tags , or add some [basic authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php). I wouldn't assume that no one will find the web form. This combined with Moussa's answer will keep it safe.